# xpath: select parent and filtered children

Tags: xpath

Given an xml block of:

```
<parent>
    <child id="1" />
    <child id="2" />
</parent>
```

How might I use xpath to return

```
<parent>
    <child id="1" />
</parent>
```

Based on a filter for `id="1"` (not firstchild).

I am not looking for an xslt or xquery solution.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With just XPath, you can't.

XPath allows you to query (select) nodes from an XML document tree, but it can't modify a tree or create new nodes. So if you select the original `<parent>` node, it will have two `<child>` children, and you can't change that. In order to get a `<parent>` with only one child, you'd have to either modify the original `<parent>` to delete its other child, or create a new `<parent>`.

You could do this with XSLT, as you alluded to; or a number of other XML tree-building technologies. If you tell us what kind of platform you're building on, we could suggest ones that are most relevant to your platform.

Comment: Thanks LarsH,  I was afraid of that.  I have a set up where I am able to pass in an xpath to a service and get a response.  If I was able to get a filtered collection of the parent and selected children it would have allowed me to pass work off to the xpath based service.