# Xpath - select a html node, but only some child

Tags: xpath

I have search all the internet, but I cannot find a solution :(. Please, help.

With following html:

```
<div>
    <span>span</span>
    <a href="#">anchor</a>
    <img>some image</img>
</div>
```

What would be the xpath to select the div and all the children, but the anchor, like:

```
<div>
    <span>span</span>
    <img>some image</img>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: With XPath alone it is not possible.  I asked the same question a while back :-)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750323/xpath-select-parent-and-filtered-children

Comment: @JonSG: Agreed.  Voting to close as a duplicate to your question.